# How do I scaffold when creating a Controller that represents more than 1 Entity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have Entity Framework modeling a legacy database that has about 30 tables. I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and would love to use scaffolding based on an Entity in my EDM. I have seen a ton of examples on this but I am running into an issue. My needs are not so cookie cutter as the examples I have seen which are like this: create a Controller that scaffolds a 'Customer' entity, and upon saving changes the Controller action takes in a Customer as it's parameter and using model binding all is well after the following is done:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     db.Customers.AddObject(customer);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Index");  
   }
 }
```

Perfect and pretty right; well this does not work for me. In my situation my screen needs fields from about 6 different entities and updates back to those same 6 entities.

So a 2 part question:

1. How do I even scaffold my controller and resulting view(s) when it is not a simple 1 entity to 1 screen deal like the simple example from above?
2. Will I still be able to use model binding to persist changes back to my entities since once again the resulting view will be a result of about 6 different entities, and without a lot of manual updating of properties on each individual entity?

If I am totally off base please guide me back. I want to know exactly how I accomplish this task as it will happen repeatedly throughout my MVC application and I need to know how to still use scaffolding and model binding when possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run into a scenario like this, it's time to start considering using ViewModels and EditModels, which are models dedicated to showing the exact properties needed by the View.

One strategy for doing this:

1. Create new folders in your project: ViewModels and EditModels.
2. For each details view, add a ViewModel class, and for each edit/create view, add an EditModel class.
3. In your controller, map from your entities to your ViewModel/EditModel when the page is first requested. On postbacks, perform validation and map from you EditModel back to your entities.

A few notes:

- This does add some work, but it's really the only solid way to take advantage of the strongly-typed view capability of MVC.
- To minimize the tedium of going from entities to ViewModels, you can use something like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to automatically map between properties with the same name (and set up rules for the remaining mappings).
- Some manual work will likely be needed to go from EditModels back to entities. AutoMapper can handle some scenarios, but it's probably not the ideal tool for that type of mapping (it works much better for going from an entity to a ViewModel). I have heard of people using the command pattern and rules engines for performing the mapping back to entities, but thus far, a truly detailed explanation or tutorial for these techniques has evaded me.

**ViewModel example (from the NerdDinner tutorial)**

```
public class DinnerFormViewModel {

    // Properties
    public Dinner     Dinner    { get; private set; }
    public SelectList Countries { get; private set; }

    // Constructor
    public DinnerFormViewModel(Dinner dinner) {
        Dinner = dinner;
        Countries = new SelectList(PhoneValidator.AllCountries, dinner.Country);
    }
}

// controller actions

[Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit(int id) {

    Dinner dinner = dinnerRepository.GetDinner(id);

    return View(new DinnerFormViewModel(dinner));
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection) {

    Dinner dinner = dinnerRepository.GetDinner(id);

    try {
        UpdateModel(dinner);

        dinnerRepository.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id=dinner.DinnerID });
    }
    catch {
        ModelState.AddModelErrors(dinner.GetRuleViolations());

        return View(new DinnerFormViewModel(dinner));
    }
}
```

Source: http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part6.htm

Comment: Since I am relatively new to ASP.NET MVC, could you post a link or show some examples please?

Comment: A great example is NerdDinner: http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/77871. I'll post a few snippets from that project to get you started.

Comment: Actually, I think this is a better link: http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part6.htm. It talks about using a ViewModel directly.

Comment: Ok I read Part 6 and portions of Part 5 to see what the `UpdateModel` method does. If I have your explanation correct, I create Custom-Shaped ViewModel classes that incorporate 1..n entities for displaying. Modelbinding will occur with the ViewModel class not the model class. Once I have the updated form data via modelbinding in my ViewModel object, I will have to segregate it back out manually to update 1..n underlying entities or use something like Automapper to try and have it done for me. Is this the correct sequence?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, except that Automapper is generally better at going from entities to view models than from view models back to entities. For simple cases, it will probably work in both directions, but if you are doing any "unflattening", you might want to look into ValueInjecter (http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/).